# Dimension formulae of this linear transformation in terms of dimension of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $U$ & $V$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$. Let a linear transformation $T : U\times V\to V$ be defined as $T(u,v)=u+v$. How to express the dimension formulae for $T$ in terms of dimension of subspaces of $V$?

Comment: $T$ is bilinear.

Comment: 1. Is one of the summands really the whole space $V$? It's unnecessary to say that $V$ is a subspace of $V$, unless you intended to pick a different letter, which changes the question quite substantially. 2. What are "dimension formulae" of an operator?

Comment: Or do you see it somehow as $T : W \to V$ with $W = U \times V$?

Comment: @mvw Not if $U \times V$ is taken as the direct product.

Comment: By dimension formulae I mean what are the nullity & rank of the transformation

Comment: You mean $\DeclareMathOperator{dim}{dim}\DeclareMathOperator{img}{img}\dim \ker T + \dim \img T = n$?

Comment: I actually made a typing mistake in the question. The second subspace is not $V$ but some other subspace $W$. Anyways the question is still very trivial. Sorry for such a trivial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel of $T$ is $\{\,(u,-u)\mid u\in U\,\}\subseteq U\times V$ whose dimension is $\dim(U)$. The rank nullity theorem here gives $\dim(U\times V)=\dim(\ker(T))+\dim(\operatorname{Im}(T))$ which becomes (as $T$ is clearly surjective) $\dim(U)+\dim(V)=\dim(U)+\dim(V)$, which if not a profound discovery, is certainly true.